# How can I compare CSV to AD users and disable users not in CSV?

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

As a process to disable users, I have a CSV where users are identified by employeeID and not username.  I need to loop through and compare the CSV to AD users, and any AD user not in the CSV needs to be disabled.  This is what I have so far, but it's not working.  I'll admit I'm still fairly new to powershell scripting, so any help would be much appreciated.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

Import-Csv -Path c:\ADTerm.csv | foreach {Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "ou=Test,ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" -Identity $_.employeeID} | Where {$_ -ne $null} | Disable-ADAccount -Identity $_.employeeID
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the csv contents? And the format of username vs employee I'd? Not real data just example data. Also what errors do you get? Also, may just be a typo in the post but you are missing a closing curly brace `}` at the end of the 2nd line to close out the `foreach`

Comment: Hi Jarrod, please pick one of the users from that list and then run this command.  `Get-ADUser -Identity <random user's Employee ID>` can you resolve a user?

Comment: Ignore my comment about the missing brace, I can't read ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant really fit this all in a comment without it looking horrible so lets start with this.

You are combining `-Filter` and `-Identity` which most likely wont net the results you are looking for. Use Identity to get one specific user or filter to get one to many. Looking at TechNet for [Get-AdUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617241.aspx) you will see Identity only matches values to:

> - DistinguishedName
> - objectGUID
> - objectSid
> - sAMAccountName

In that regard I see you have a column for `EmployeeID`. I'm guessing that those are not `SamAccountName` which is one of the values that `-Identity` supports. I feel that you could do with the following changes.

```
$IDs = Import-Csv -Path c:\ADTerm.csv | Select-object -ExpandProperty EmployeeID
Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "ou=Test,ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" -Properties EmployeeID | 
        Where-Object{$_.EmployeeID -and ($IDs -notcontains $_.EmployeeID)} | Disable-ADAccount
```

Update the `get-aduser` to get all users in that OU. `Get-Aduser` does not return the EmployeeID by default so we use `-Properties` to specify it. Filter all those users that have employeeID but not one in the list. `Disable-ADAccount` will take the output of `Get-AdUser` nicely so there is not need to specify the account again.

Depending you might be storing this value as `EmployeeNumber` in AD. This is also dependent on your having a csv file with a column for `EmployeeNumber`

Comment: @BoogaRoo thanks for noticing that. I made a lazy edit for now. Will improve later if we are on the right track. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help that makes total sense now.  The script you posted works except I just changed the "Disable-Account" to "Disable-ADAccount".  Thanks again!